# How to differentiate whether user is coming from FB app or the standalone app

Tags: facebook

I've a rails application that acts as a Facebook app as well as a standalone app. Now I need to differentiate from where the user is accessing the app.

What's the easiest and sure-shot way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The http [Referer [sic] field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36).